# emulate zsh multios in dash (multiple redirections)

Tags: shell, zsh, io-redirection, dash

in `zsh`, when the option `multios` is enabled, I can pipe output to two different processes, ie:

```
cat /dev/sda > sda.img | sha256sum > sda.img.sha256
```

How could I achieve the same in `dash`, ie `/bin/sh` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tee` to copy the stream to a file and pipe the result over to let `sha256sum` read from standard input and write it to a separate file. The read from standard input designator `-` is optional though

```
</dev/sda tee sda.img | sha256sum - > sda.img.sha256
```

which of course should work on any minimal shell like `dash`.

It's actually more efficient here than using `zsh`'s multios as the data goes through fewer pipes. Here, it's read once by `tee`, once by `sha256sum` and written twice by `tee` while with the multios approach, it's read once by `cat`, once by the zsh's internal teeing process (through a pipe), once by `sha256sum` and written once by `cat`, twice by the internal teeing process.

On `ksh` or `bash` where process substitution(`>(..)`) is supported like in `zsh`, you could use that

```
< /dev/sda tee >(sha256sum > sda.img.sha256) > sda.img
```

Comment: Note that the process substitution approach has no advantage whatsoever over the pipe one, only drawbacks (here that sha256sum is not waited for with some shells, and as a result `sda.img.sha256` may not be populated yet by the time you run the next  command).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks Stephane, as ever for your valuable feedback